# Django - you have an error in your sql syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to execute a simple MySQL query that will work on MySQL, while it gives any kind of error on Django.

Here is the query:

```
Summary = myTable.objects.raw("select FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime, '%%Y/%%m/%%d') as ndate,count(id) as query_count from myTable group by ndate order by query_count DESC")
```

This line will give me the following error:

```
Raw query must include the primary key
```

But if i edit the query to the following: `select id FROM_UNIXITIME....`
I will get the following error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d') as ndate,count(id) as query_count from myTable' at line 1")
```

And here is my model:

```
class myTable(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    query = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unixtime = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mytable'
```

The query, basically, should only count how many rows there are for this table every day and give the following output: `{'2020/06/28': 30, '2020/06/27': 20 ... }`. Can anyone help me out on how to make the query work, or at least how to do the same query but using the Django ORM, since using raw queries is being a nightmare? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This part `select id FROM_UNIXITIME....` must have comma after id so it should look like this:

```
select id, FROM_UNIXITIME....
```

And also group by must have id so it should look like this (if functions are correct):

```
select id, FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime, '%%Y/%%m/%%d') as ndate,count(id) as query_count from myTable group by id,ndate order by query_count DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem with this is that it won't give me the output that i was getting with the original query on MySQL, which is a list of days and the total number of records for every day. If i change to this, as Django wants, i will get a long list of "1" with a date near

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer to use Django's queryset instead of raw queries .
Basically if you want to count the no of distinct unixtime field in the above table , you can use the below queryset :

`myTable.objects.all().values('unixtime').annotate(count = Count('unixtime'))`

In the above query , you will get all the unixtime using values queryset and can apply aggregation using annotate to get the distinct unixtime with their coount .

Comment: You would also import Count using :
from django.db.models import Count

Comment: Thank you! The problem with this, is that i will get a long list of "1", instead of getting something like {'date': x, 'count': 20}, which means counting how many  records there are for every day

Comment: You would be getting in the same format as required with the above queryset . Assign the queryset output to a variable and apply for loop on it .
Eg: 

`queryset = myTable.objects.all().values('unixtime').annotate(count = Count('unixtime'))`
`for var in queryset:
        print var`